What on my system is using Cloudflare?
I am running a pretty vanilla Ubuntu box.  Just about the only things I use on it are Firefox and Software Updater.  The computer is connected through an opnsense router.  The router is setup to block all DNS connections except those going to my chosen DNS resolver which it connects to using DOT.  The settings show the DNS ip to be my router.  Yet it is detecting and blocking DOH connections to 1.1.1.3, Cloudflare.  Initially this was blocking updates but I got around that by setting the DNS parameter in /etc/systemd/system.conf but something is still trying to connect to Cloudflare!!  It is not Firefox which has DOH turned off and which is working fine (DNS is not blocked).  Does anyone know where to change this setting?

Find out which process is connecting to 1.1.1.3 by doing something like sudo netstat -tunp | grep -F "1.1.1.3".

Sorry, It is a desktop system, minimal install, version 22.04LTS.  I tried the netstat command recomended by Jos but got command not found. Researched and found I had to install net-tools.  Did that. Each line shows "tcp  0  0 the ip and port of the computer 1.1.1.3:443  TIME_WAIT" but not process name.   I did make a change in the opnsense router adding a NAT rule to forward anything going to 1.1.1.3 to the DNS provider of my choice so the requests are no linger blocked but I would like to know who is making the request.
